# Neo4j Large Movie Database failed to start

Tags: graph, neo4j, graph-databases

I'm trying to import the large Movie dataset found [here](https://neo4j.com/developer/movie-database/#_import_instructions):

I've following the instructions but when I override the graph.db and try to restart the server I get the following message:

`Database failed to start: DB closed with exit code 1. Check the logs`

Checking the logs I then get the following message:

`ERROR Neo4j cannot be started because the database files require upgrading and upgrades are disabled in the configuration. Please set 'dbms.allow_upgrade' to 'true' in your configuration file and try again.`

The problem is when I check the conf file, `dbms.allow_upgrade` is already set to `true`.

My Neo4j Version is 3.3.2 Enterprise and the MovieDB was meant for an older version (2.1) but its the latest version on their website. Any ideas?

Comment: did you restart your db after that?

Comment: Sure that there is no # on that conf line ?

Comment: The ruby generates cypher. Capture the cypher into a file. Run it with cypher shell. Im on a small screen but havent seen any cypher version specified